# cron jobs function without using http server request in php with yii framework

Tags: php, yii, cron

I have a millions sms as well as email ,which I want execute by using cron with Yii framework functino.
Some time process goes stuck due to server hits .
Now I just wondering ,that is there any console solution for execute our php function for infinite time.

Please suggest to me .Thanks in advance .

Regards,
Sanjeev Kr Goswami

Comment: PHP by default in console have time limit set to 0 - so script wont  be terminated. Console command in cron - best way to do such tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good day, I hope i can help you,

1. Php stablish by default a 30 sec limit to run a quer unless you specify something else by the php command set_time_limit wich runs in seconds, 0 meaning no time, check out that yii makes use of this feature...
2. then you have got to check memory usage, if your loop is no optimal enough you will be saving info on every loop until you run out of memory , 2 solutions for these,

1.1 upgrading memory with memory_limit function/php.ini conf 
1.2 (best choice) debug your code to see memory consumption...

1.3 You also have to ensure that your smtp relay and sms service is able to take those millions Emails or Tasks and that you are not been blocked by security. Check out doc of your providers and finally try to run smaller amounts to find breaking point, i suggest that if thare is no way to find the exact break point you make use of Zenon Paradox [Achilles and the tortoise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes#Achilles_and_the_tortoise) to find it out

1.4 (with a little bit of advice) if those steps have been already acomplished you could start saying server down by hits, and you can blame php / apache all you want cause you are right, then go to take a coffee and come back to debug , debug, debug, rewrite functions in an optimal way. I assure there are processes running millions of loop in php and no hit failure when the correct environment is set up. to get help with this i recommend https://wiki.koumbit.net/ApacheDebugging

Regarding running in console mode i strongly suggest you read this http://www.larryullman.com/2010/10/07/creating-a-yii-console-application/
From Php Jedi Larry Ullman, it explains how to create your console apps with yii 1

My regards.